# Evernote OAuth Login Javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth, parse-platform, evernote

I try to create a Evernote Connection for my webapp via OAuth(using OAuth JS) just as described on the Evernote webpage. My problem is that the respond always is successfull but the data empty.

```
var hostName = "http://sandbox.evernote.com"; 
var options,oauth;
options = {
    consumerKey: consumer_key,
    consumerSecret: "consumer_secret,
    callbackUrl : "https://testEvernote.parseapp.com",
    signatureMethod : "HMAC-SHA1",
};
oauth = OAuth(options);
oauth.request({'method': 'GET', 'url': hostName + '/oauth', 
               'success': function(data){
                   alert("Succes:"+data.text);
               }, 'failure': function(data){
                   alert("Failure:"+data.text);
               }});
```

Anyone any idea what is wrong with this code?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evernote does not allow client side Javascript access.  Evernote requires the use of Node.js (or Apache Cordova) if you want to use Javascript to access the Evernote API.

The npm module provided by Evernote includes helper functions to get OAuth working.

Install the Evernote npm module via:

```
  $npm install evernote
```

Below is the simplest single file example of implementing OAuth in a Evernote application I could put together.  Just change the values of `CONSUMER_KEY` and `CONSUMER_SECRET` below and it should run just fine if you've installed Evernote:

```
var Evernote = require('evernote').Evernote;
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

CONSUMER_KEY="Put your consumer key here";
CONSUMER_SECRET="put your consumer secret here";

if (CONSUMER_KEY === "Put your consumer key here"){
  console.error("\nPlease enter your Evernote consumer key and secret\n\nIf you don't have a key you can get one at:\nhttps://dev.evernote.com/#apikey\n")
  process.exit(1)
}

var global = {};
global.oauthToken = '';
global.oauthSecret = '';

function getOauthVerifier(url) {
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]oauth_verifier=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var handler = function(request, response) {
  var params = url.parse(request.url)
  var pathname = params.pathname;
  console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

  var client = new Evernote.Client ({
    consumerKey: "Put your consumer key here",
    consumerSecret: "put your consumer secret here",
    sandbox: true
  });

  if (pathname == "/"){
    var callbackUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/oauth';

    client.getRequestToken(callbackUrl, function(err, oauthToken, oauthSecret, results){
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        global.oauthToken = oauthToken;
        global.oauthSecret = oauthSecret;
        console.log("set oauth token and secret");
        var authorizeUrl = client.getAuthorizeUrl(oauthToken);
        console.log(authorizeUrl);
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        response.write("Please <a href=\""+authorizeUrl+"\">click here</a> to authorize the application");
        response.end();
      }
    });
  }
  else if (pathname == "/oauth"){
    client.getAccessToken(
      global.oauthToken, 
      global.oauthSecret, 
      getOauthVerifier(params.search), 
      function(error, oauthAccessToken, oauthAccessTokenSecret, results) {
        if(error) {
          console.log("error\n\n\n");
          console.log(error);
        }
        else {
          response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
          response.write(oauthAccessToken);
          response.end();
        }   
      }
    );
  }
  else {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
    response.write("not a valid URL <a href=\"/\"> GO HOME </a>");
    response.end();
  }
};


http.createServer(handler).listen(8888);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but It is still very clumsy to create a connection using Parse.com.